# Drop Check command not working MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to drop the following check constraint in mySQL:

> constraint music_artist_genre_name_ck check (genre_name in ('Country', 'Hip Hop', 'Jazz', 'Pop', 'Rock')

I have tried the command

> ALTER TABLE music_artist DROP CHECK music_artist_genre_name_ck;

I am struggling to understand why this is not working. Can someone give me the correct command to drop checks.

Comment: `... DROP CONSTRAINT ...`?

Answer (score 0):

CHECK constraint definitions are ignored in MySQL.

Example:

```
create table check_test (
    val int,
    constraint my_check check (val in (0, 1))
);

show create table check_test;
```

The result is:

```
CREATE TABLE `check_test` (
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/MAZG17623

As you can see, there is no CHECK constraint, thus nothing to drop.